# File uploaded successfully to s3 using serverless api but it doesn't open(corrupted)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, graphql, serverless-framework

I've the following ts code that submit a file came from GraphQL API to my AWS S3 bucket. 
it works perfectly when I run the project using nodejs http lib, but when I run it using `sls offline start` or from aws lambda function it uploads the file but it doesn't open(like a damaged file) - **except text files.**

the code:

```
const fileStream = data.createReadStream()
const uploadParams = {
                Bucket: 'XXX',
                Key: data.filename,
                Body: fileStream,
                ContentType: data.mimetype,
                ContentEncoding: data.encoding,
                ACL: 'public-read',
};
const result = await s3.upload(uploadParams).promise()
```

data object looks like this:

```
{ filename: '11083626_830419647032756_2338667058698516671_n.jpg',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream] }
```

I've tried converting the createReadStream to buffer and use s3.putObject() function instead but still not working.

Added the following configrations to allow binary files in `serverless.yml` but still the same problem:

```
provider:
    apiGateway:
        binaryMediaTypes:
            - '*/*'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**after adding:**

```
provider:
    apiGateway:
        binaryMediaTypes:
            - '*/*'
```

- or instead of '*/*' in my case only 'multipart/form-data'

it worked in **lambda AWS** after making **deploy**, but still not working offline using `sls offline start` it might be a bug in their code or I should add additional thing to let it work offline